# How does 「あいつは意気地なんだと」 translate into "he's a coward"?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

[There's this sentence on Tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/1155835):
 - According to her, he is a coward.

For which the following translation was added:
 - 彼女に言わせれば、あいつは意気地なんだと。

The first part is clear to me (causative + conditional: 言う -> 言わせる -> 言わせれば - "if (you) make her say"), but I can't figure out how the second part works. AFAIK 意気地 means [self-respect; self-confidence; guts; etc.](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%84%8F%E6%B0%97%E5%9C%B0) so an antonym of "coward". As such, 「なんだと」at the end must somehow imply a negation... or something. I couldn't find any reference to that kind of use for such a sentence ending.

Ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe this is a typo for [意気地なし](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%84%8F%E6%B0%97%E5%9C%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97). なんだと is [explanatory-なのだ](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/) + quotative-と.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes no sense.

> 「あいつは意気地{いくじ}なんだと。」

***does not*** mean:

> "He is a coward."

「意気地」 would need to be changed to 「意気地なし」, which means "***a coward***"

「～～なんだと」 is an expression of hearsay meaning "**It is said ~~**", "**I hear ~~**", etc.  Thus, it is used correctly.

Comment: Got it, thanks!